# How can I pass data from a scene to another in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm creating a "space invaders" kinda of game and I'm really having problems with passing score from my WorldScene to my GameOverScene.

I already tried to use init: function() to pass data but I'm probably doing something wrong...

I'm using Phaser 3.

A little of my WorldScene:

```
    constructor() {
        super( { key: 'WorldScene'} );
    }

    preload()
    {

    }
    create()
    {

        var score = 0;
 (...)
```

```
            //a scene comeca de novo
            //this.scene.restart();
            this.scene.start('GameOverScene', {score_n: this.score} );
          }, [], this);
```

And my GameOverScene in game.js

````
  Extends: Phaser.Scene,

  initialize:

  function GameOverScene ()
  {
      Phaser.Scene.call(this, { key: 'GameOverScene' });

  },

  init: function (data)
    {
        console.log('init', data);
        this.scoreFinal = data.score_n;
    },

  preload: function ()
  {
    //background inicial
    this.load.image('back_menu', 'assets/img_espaco.png');
  },

  create: function (data)
  {

    let backg = this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'back_menu');
        backg.setOrigin(0, 0);

       //texto do game over
        gameOver_text = this.add.text(320, 150, 'Game Over', { fontSize: '70px', fill: '#FF0000' });
        gameOver_text.setOrigin(0.5);

        //score
        scoreFinal_txt = this.add.text(320, 210, 'Pontuação Final: '+ this.scoreFinal, { fontSize: '20px', fill: '#FFF' });
        scoreFinal_txt.setOrigin(0.5);

        //botao de recomeçar
        bt_novo = this.add.text(320, 260, 'Voltar ao Inicio', { fontSize: '30px', color: '#ffffff' }).setInteractive();
        bt_novo.setOrigin(0.5);

        //se o botao for carregado começa o jogo
        bt_novo.on('pointerdown', function (event) { this.scene.start('MenuScene'); }, this );
        bt_novo.on('pointerover', function (event) { bt_novo.setStyle({ fill: '#ff0'}); } )
        bt_novo.on('pointerout', function (event) { bt_novo.setStyle({ fill: '#ffffff'}); } )


  },

}); ```


My scoreFinal_txt shows: "Pontuaçao Final: undefined"
````

Comment: did my answer work  for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass additional scene data via the second param in `this.scene.start(key, data)`

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-phaser-scene-data-transfer)

```
class IntroScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({
      key: 'intro'
    });
  }

  create() {
    const btn = this.add.text(20, 20, 'Hello', { fontSize: '30px', color: '#ffffff' }).setInteractive();
    btn.addListener('pointerup', () => {
      console.log('game started click');
      this.scene.start('game', 666); // second argument enables passing data
    });
  }
}

class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({
      key: 'game'
    });
  }

  /**
   * @param data passed to scene at startup
   */
  create(data) {
    console.log('game started', data);
    this.add.text(20, 20, `Game ${data}`, { fontSize: '30px', color: '#ffffff' });
  }
}
```